# Exercise Package compilation error

Tags: loops, exercises

I have a series of Questions saved as separate tex files and want to loop over them to place them in the document using the exercise package.

If I loop over the Questions I get a compile error.

However, If I put a Question in first and then loop over the Questions there is no error. 
This seems a bit of a hack - is there a reason that this is happening? Is there a way I can change the Exercise package so that it behaves?

NB: I'm working in overleaf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
\input{Q1} %if I comment out this line then compilation error

\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
{%
\input{Q\i} 
%Q1,...Q5 are separate text files that all look like \Question this is a question
}%
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\foreach groups the loop body and so it not suited here: exercise wants to identify the first question.

You can use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` from the pgfplots package instead. Or some other loop command which doesn't group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\intstepinline{\int_step_inline:nn}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}

\intstepinline{5} %starts from 1 by default. 
{%
\input{Q#1}
}%
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```